# Redirecting with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I have a method in some controller that is being used to display something inside a twig template. The content of this template depends on the value of a parameter passed to this method.

The code is:

```
class FooController {
  public function fooBarAction($parameter)
  {
    // do something
    if($_POST)
    {
      // do something
      return $this->redirect('foo_bar');
    }
    return $this->render('AcmeBundle:view.html.twig', [
      'content' => $parameter
    ]);
  }
}
```

So having some menu in this twig template, I create a couple of links to the `foo_bar` route with different parameters, like:

```
<a href="{{ url('foo_bar', {'parameter', 'aaa'}) }}">aaa</a><br>
<a href="{{ url('foo_bar', {'parameter', 'bbb'}) }}">bbb</a>
```

What if I'd like to do this with ajax, so that the page loads faster? How could I do this?

So far I've created click event in jQuery, that catches the menu clicks, and gets parameter's value, but what now? How do I do this? I have no idea where to begin.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of the redirect? Why wouldnt you use a forward or just render a different template?

Comment: I cant use different template as I base this template on the array, that is generated from the db inside the controller...so everything has to go through the controller.

Comment: I just want to make a simple route based redirect using ajax.

Comment: Right... but you can choose what template to load in the controller... So instead of redirecting to another action why don't you just return that template? Or use a `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller::forward()` instead?

Comment: Your simplified example isnt properly higlighting the problem because what you are asking to do (an ajax redirect) should only be done under a certain set of circumstances which your example does not adhere to - you probably don't need to go down this path but i can recommend a viable alternative because its not clear what requirement you are trying to meet by redirecting.